# Regex to delete everything before it, including regex

Tags: regex, bash

I need to do something like this

Input:

```
text text text text text text text Total number = 2 remaining remaining remaining
text text text text text text Total number = 10 remaining remaining  
text text text text text text Total number = 3  remaining remaining
```

what I am trying to do is to extract everything AFTER

```
Total number = x
```

so,

Total number = x should also be removed, in short first "remaining" part should be the first 
word in each line, like this:

Output:

```
remaining remaining remaining
remaining remaining
remaining remaining
```

Comment: You can only match in RegEx, you cannot delete/replace. That depends on what language you're using.

Comment: How about simply: `.*Total number = [\d]+` ?

Comment: Sorry, i am trying to make a bash script to do it, i've tried sed '0,/<regex>/d' inputfile > outputfile that is deleting everything inside a logfile ABOVE the regex, including regex itself...now i need something similar to that which is doing it in each line of logfile...

Comment: The `d` command of `sed` deletes the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F 'Total number = [0-9]+ *' '{print $2}' file
remaining remaining remaining
remaining remaining  
remaining remaining
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the language, but here goes:

sed:

```
s/^.*Total number = [[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*//
```

AWK:

```
{ gsub("^.*Total number = [[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*", "") ; print }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex pattern

```
.*Total number =\s*\d+\s* (.*)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oG1xF3)